# How do I call python setup.py install from scons?

Tags: installation, scons, setup.py

I am converting a build from make to scons. The program contains python code, cuda, and c++. At the end of the make, "python setup.py install" is called to properly install the module in site-packages. How do I call this in scons? It seems non-productive to copy all the code in the working setup.py file into the scons scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the scons [Command builder](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#chap-builders-commands). With the Command builder, you can run any command as you would from the command line.

```
env = Environment()
...
py_install = env.Command('always.install', ['setup.py'],
                         'python setup.py install')
Alias('install', py_install)
```

In the example above, I use a dummy target *always.install* to force the install command to always run (there are other ways to do this, but that's another topic). The dependency list contains only the *setup.py* file, you may have other dependencies you want to list here. The third item is the command line. The recommend scanning the [scons Users Guide](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html); there's a lot of useful information in there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have used the users guide and it's helpful. I ALMOST have it working. The problem seems to be that I need to be in the python directory for the setup.py to work. The env.Command is running from the root directory. I tried putting a "cd python" in front of the call to python, but I get an error that the system cannot find the specified path. Perhaps I should make this a builder so I can use the chdir, but we like building multithreaded and it seems this can cause a problem. You would think it would be easy to cd to a different directory, but that isn't the case.

Comment: If your `env.Command()` is running from `python/SConscript`, then try this: `env.Command(..., chdir=1)`. (If your `env.Command()` is running from your `SConstruct`, then `chdir=1` will have no useful effect.)

Comment: Thanks @Rob. And you can use `chdir='python'` with the Command builder in the SConstruct.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. I ended up getting it to work by putting a quick python function like so:

def build_install(target, source, env):
 os.chdir('./python')
 os.system("python setup.py install")
 os.chdir("..")